# Need help formatting Unix Date from XML output.

Tags: facebook, unix, date, replace

I have an events feed from facebook that outputs data in XML format. The dates/ times are in epoch (unix) format, I think. Like so:

```
 <start_time>1319506200</start_time><end_time>1319511600</end_time>
```

This is dynamic information (events created by a facebook page).

I am using php file_get_contents to place the xml output in my html.

How in the world can I convert the unix dates to a user friendly format? I am at a total loss.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )`

Extract the timestamp value from the xml string and pass in as argument #2 to date, as argument #1 you should supply your preferred format string, for example 'Y-m-d T:i:s'

Extracting he timestamp could probably look something like this:
Given that you have the event feed output data stored in a string, in this case $xmlstr

```
$facebooksomething = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
date('Y-m-d T:i:s', $facebooksomething->starttime);
```

Comment: I apologize for not knowing, but how do I extract the value? I understand the Date string concept, but how do extract the timestamp in order to pass it through the php?

Comment: Thank you - I will see what I can come up with - I don't really get php yet :) I am barely functional with CSS and HTML, lol

Answer (score 1):

Finally got this figured out! :) Woohoo! (changed from the xml feed to json feed by the way) This is what ended up working:

```
   $start_date = date('F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime($json_output2->start_time));
   $end_date = date('g:i a', strtotime($json_output2->end_time));
```

Here is my full code:

```
<?php

 $jsonurl = "https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID/events?access_token=MYYOKEN";
 $json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
 $json_output = json_decode($json);

 foreach ( $json_output->data as $data)

{

 $jsonurl2 = "https://graph.facebook.com/$data->id/";
 $json2 = file_get_contents($jsonurl2,0,null,null);
 $json_output2 = json_decode($json2);
 $start_date = date('F j, Y, g:i a', strtotime($json_output2->start_time));
 $end_date = date('g:i a', strtotime($json_output2->end_time));

echo "{$json_output2->name}\n";
echo "<br>"; 
echo "{$start_date}\n";
echo "&nbsp;-&nbsp;"; 
echo "{$end_date}\n";
echo "<br>"; 
echo "{$json_output2->description}\n";
echo "<br>Where: "; 
echo "{$json_output2->location}\n";
echo "<br><br>";
 }
 ?>
```